# MYSQL Sending data taking forever. removing ORDER BY or inserting New Row is faster

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-order-by

I'm having an issue with a SELECT statement. I find that if I have a single row of data as the result and using ORDER BY it slows it right down. As soon as I either remove the ORDER BY or add another row of data it returns it in reasonable time. My data returned for the most part will have more than 1 result (hence the LIMIT 2) but there are some cases where there is only an individual row and it's stalling things.

```
Profiling
Status  Time
starting    0.000082
checking permissions    0.000007
Opening tables  0.000020
System lock 0.000016
init    0.000043
optimizing  0.000021
statistics  0.000016
preparing   0.000016
executing   0.000004
Sorting result  0.000005
Sending data    15.276259
end 0.000013
query end   0.056590
closing tables  0.000030
freeing items   0.000156
logging slow query  0.000008
logging slow query  0.000007
cleaning up 0.000009

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 15.3337 sec)

SELECT expiration, strike, category, last, volume, stock_price
FROM chains
WHERE option_id =  'AMZN^^120203P00165000'
AND DATE( id ) = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
AND TIME( id ) BETWEEN  '09:30:00' AND  '16:00:00'
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

As soon as I insert a new row with the same option_id value and a different id(timestamp) value the results is this:

```
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.2272 sec)
```

OR if I remove the ORDER BY id DESC it returns a similar timed result, less than a second.

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.5024 sec)
```

The SQL EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys  key      key_len ref    rows Extra
1   SIMPLE      chains  index   NULL           PRIMARY  27      NULL   2    Using where
```

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chains` (
  `id` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `option_id` varchar(21) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` date NOT NULL,
  `strike` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `category` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `last` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `volume` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `openint` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `stock_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `stock_volume` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`option_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

In the end, im trying to grab the "latest" two results.

Thanks ahead of time for the help! It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the definitions for the stages shown by profiling is very sparse, but from what I've found, it's likely that those times aren't exactly the times spent on its respective operation, but time from the last operation to the beginning of the specified operation.  What this would mean is that it's not really the sending data that is taking so long, but actually the sorting, which makes sense since the query isn't using an index.  The `ORDER BY` is taking so long because it has to scan and sort the entire table before it can decide which are the first two rows; without it, it just uses the first two rows it finds.

With this query, you should at least be using an index on `option_id`.  A multiple index on `option_id` and `id` would likely significantly improve the performance of this query.

P.S. Go Go Nugget Necromancy!